# Sinatra streaming response with headers

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to proxy remote files through a Sinatra application. This requires streaming an HTTP response with headers from a remote source back to the client, but I can't figure out how to set the headers of the response while using the streaming API inside the block provided by `Net::HTTP#get_response`.

For example, this will not set response headers:

```
get '/file' do
  stream do |out|
    uri = URI("http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/ipad_user_guide.pdf")
    Net::HTTP.get_response(uri) do |file|
      headers 'Content-Type' => file.header['Content-Type']

      file.read_body { |chunk| out << chunk }
    end
  end
end
```

And this results in the error: `Net::HTTPOK#read_body called twice (IOError)`:

```
get '/file' do
  response = nil
  uri = URI("http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/ipad_user_guide.pdf")
  Net::HTTP.get_response(uri) do |file|
    headers 'Content-Type' => file.header['Content-Type']

    response = stream do |out|
      file.read_body { |chunk| out << chunk }
    end
  end
  response
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but after thinking a bit about this it appears to me that when setting the response headers from inside the `stream` helper block, those headers don't get applied into the response because the execution of that block is actually being *deferred*. So, probably, the block gets evaluated and the response headers get set *before* it begins executing.

A possible workaround for this is issuing a HEAD request before streaming back the contents of the file.

For example:

```
get '/file' do
  uri = URI('http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/ipad_user_guide.pdf')

  # get only header data
  head = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    http.head(uri.request_uri)
  end

  # set headers accordingly (all that apply)
  headers 'Content-Type' => head['Content-Type']

  # stream back the contents
  stream do |out|
    Net::HTTP.get_response(uri) do |f| 
      f.read_body { |ch| out << ch }
    end
  end
end
```

It may not be ideal for your use case because of the additional request but it should be small enough to not be much of a problem (delay) and it adds the benefit that your app may be able to react if that request fails before sending back any data.

Hope it helps.